# COMException when instantiating class from a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am new to .NET and windows in general (but have experience with C/C++) and am running into a problem when I try to instantiate a class that is defined in a dll.

**MY SETUP:**

In Visual Studio 2013, my solution contains two projects:

1. c# windows application (.NET 4.5)
2. a c++ dll (inherited from older code) - call it dllLib.dll

As a pre-build step for the c# application, I generate a COM interop from the dll using tlbimp. This gives me interop.dllLib.dll, which I add as a reference in the c# project.

When I try to instantiate a dll class (called switchboard) from the c# project, I get the following error:

> dllLib.switchboard myclass = new dllLib.switchboard();
>
> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D7EBBF24-5620-4AED-871B-2027471FD075} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I am stumped. The dll registers without a problem (regsvr32 works). The c# app can see the Interface for the class "switchboard", and it compiles without complaint.

**THINGS I HAVE ALREADY TRIED/CHECKED:**

- Running Visual Studio as administrator
- Active Solution is Debug x86
- Project contexts are x86(c#) and Win32(dll)
- regsvr32 /n /i:user dllLib.dll is successful, but interestingly, unregistering it with /u fails.

Error message on unregistering dll:

> The call to DllUnregisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c

Any suggestions you can offer on what to try or troubleshoot are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run regsvr32 current directory should be in the same directory as the dll you are trying to register.  AND  This com dll needs to be in the debug or Release dir that your are building to when you register it.   You can overcome these limitations later but this could clear up a detail or two for you now to see the class get created and instantiated.  Running VS as administrator is relevant.  Doing a clean build can sometimes cause problems.  Make sure your com dll has its dependencies in the dir as well.

Comment: OK, I just realized that running regsvr32 dllLib.dll allows the code to run without throwing that exception. It also allows me to unregister the dll without complaint.

The dll code that I inherited was using the /n /i:user flags on the regsvr32 post build command, but my ignorance of Windows means that I am unclear what purpose this serves. Is there a security reason for doing this?